# How to apply Nested Mat-Table Grid to the third level in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a Mat-Table with nested grid with a nested json by a lot of research online and help . It has 2 grids for now . But now i have a requirement where i need an additional nested grid inside .

I tried to replicate what is done for the second level grid to generate the third level grid but the "ExpandedElements" array throws an error while generating the third level grid .

My updated JSON looks like -

```
{
name: 'Mason',
email: 'mason@test.com',
phone: '9864785214',
addresses: [
  {
    street: 'Street 1',
    zipCode: '78542',
    city: 'Kansas',
    comments: [
      {
        commenID: 1,
        comment: 'Test',
        commentStatus: 'Open'
      },
      {
        commenID: 2,
        comment: 'Test',
        commentStatus: 'Open'
      },{
        commenID: 3,
        comment: 'Test',
        commentStatus: 'Closed'
      },
    ]
  },
```

I want the comments to be an internal grid under address grid .

I have the 2 grids ready with the json in the stackblitz link -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-sia2jn?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

Can anyone help me how to proceed with the third level of grid ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a similar variable for you nested comments on your addresses:

```
innerExpandedElements: any[] = [];
```

And then add another toggle function to manage that list:

```
toggleAddress(address) {
    const index = this.innerExpandedElements.findIndex(x => x === address);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.innerExpandedElements.push(address);
    } else {
      this.innerExpandedElements.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Then in your template display when those elements are in your array:

```
*ngIf="innerExpandedElements.includes(address)"
```

I made a quick example. It uses a `ul` and doesn't have animation but should conceptually work the same.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-ynf8vb?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html